# How to implement a sort by mechanism?

Tags: typescript, currying, arrow-functions

the array.sort() is taking a function that returns a number. so usually something like this

```
myArray.sort((item1, item2) => a < b);
```

alright, what i want to have is:

```
myArray.sort(by(obj => obj.id))
```

so:

- I have an argument that is a function that returns a number from an any
- i return a function that has 2 arguments (the ones to be compared) and returns a number
- this function compares the 2 results

it should look somehow like this... unfortunately I can't get it to work with various approaches.

```
by = (getter : any => number): ((any, any) => number) => (x,y) => {
  var xValue = getter(x);
  var yValue = getter(y);

  if (xValue > yValue)
    return 1;
  else (xValue < yValue)
    return -1;
  else return 0;
}
```

am I on the right track here?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is almost ok, I would also make it generic to get extra type safety:

```
const by = <T>(getter: (v: T) => number) => (x :T, y :T) => {
    var xValue = getter(x);
    var yValue = getter(y);

    if (xValue > yValue)
        return 1;
    else if (xValue < yValue)
        return -1;
    else return 0;
}
let myArray = [
    { id : 1 },
    { id : 5 },
    { id : 3 },
    { id : 2 },
]
myArray.sort(by(o=> o.id)); // o is inferred to { id: number }, which should be helpful
```

Comment: Your, welcomed, I must admit this question opened up my mind about type inference in typescript, I did not think `o` would get inferred, but it does !